# How to fix runtime error in Shunting Yard algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, stack, runtime-error, shunting-yard

I have implemented Shunting yard algorithm using stack in c++.
Well it is working quite well on inputs from SPOJ example inputs but when I input:

1

(((a+b) * (c+r)^(t+b)-n)^(c-(d * e))-b)+(c+(e-(d^r)))

I get a runtime error.

**Note: I only get a runtime error when I call infixToPostfix() and use the above input and not when I comment it out.**
Submission to SPOJ and running on ideone(with input above) results in a runtime error.
I really can't understand this behaviour of my program, so any help is welcomed.

I have tried some random inputs and it seems to work fine on them.
Even though they had spaces around operators.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<math.h>
#include<stack>
#include<strings.h>
using namespace std;
void infixToPostfix(string st);
int pr(char s);
int main() {
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    cin.ignore();
    string st; // input string

    while(t--)
    {
        getline(cin,st);
        cin.sync();
        cout<<st<<endl;
        infixToPostfix(st);
    }
    return 0;
}

int pr(char s) // to check precedence
{
    if(s == '^')
    {
        return 4;
    }
    else if(s == '*')
    {
        return 3;
    }
    else if(s == '/')
    {
        return 3;
    }
    else if(s == '+')
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else if(s == '-')
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
void infixToPostfix(string st)
{
    stack<char>op; //stack to hold operators and bracket
    st += 'n';

    int l = st.size();
    op.push('0');
    string fst;    //final string
    for(int x = 0;x<l;x++)
    {
        if(st[x] == '(')
        {
            op.push(st[x]);

        }
        else if(st[x] == ')')
        {
            while(op.top() != '(' &&  !op.empty())
            {

                fst +=op.top();
                op.pop();
            }
            op.pop();
        }
        else if(st[x] == '+' || st[x] == '-' || st[x] == '*' ||st[x] == '/' ||st[x] == '^')
        {
            if(pr(st[x]) <= pr(op.top()))
            {
                fst += op.top();
                op.pop();
                op.push(st[x]);
            }
            else{
                op.push(st[x]);
            }
        }
        else if(st[x] == 'n'){

            while(op.size() != 0)
            {
                if(op.top() != '0')
                   {fst += op.top();}
                op.pop();
            }
        }
        else if((st[x] >= 'a' || st[x] <= 'z' )&& st[x] != ' ')
        {


            fst += st[x];
        }

    }
printf("%s\n",fst.c_str());



}
```

Comment: Have you debugged this code?

Comment: I think you need some parentheses here: else if(st[x] >= 'a' || st[x] <= 'z' && st[x] != ' ')

Comment: I have tried, used different inputs (with and without brackets and spaces)  but till now only this input is causing a problem.

Comment: Parentheses placed, still runtime error

Comment: Have you used your debugger to identify where in the code the runtime error occurs?

Comment: @BhagyaSingh With "debug your code" I don't mean "try some input", I mean: have you used a debugger to see exactly where your problem is?

Comment: @MFnx No haven't used a real debugger as per se, only tried it with different inputs.

Comment: @BhagyaSingh I recommend you to use a debugger, and if you still don't understand the problem, post your debugging results here.

Comment: You can change the order of `op.top() != '(' && !op.empty()` such that `!op.empty()` is done first and if it fails then `op.top() != '('` doesn't get evaluated.

Comment: Likewise, after the `while`, when you do `op.pop()`, check that the stack is non-empty before doing it. Also in the `if (pr(st[x]) <= pr(op.top()))` add that check, for example by adding `!op.empty() &&` to the condition.

Comment: @BhagyaSingh -- You should get yourself a compiler and debugger, test / correct your code on your machine using the input you say doesn't work.  Once that works, *then* you submit it to the online compiler.  Trying to do this with an online compiler alone, and especially since you know what input breaks your code, will be a lot of time wasted on your part.  Also, when you submit code here, please hard-code the input into the program.  No one cares about `t` or `scanf` -- you know what the input should be, so just put it directly into the program's variables.

Comment: @BhagyaSingh This is what your `main` should look like: `int main() {
 infixToPostfix("(((a+b) * (c+r)^(t+b)-n)^(c-(d * e))-b)+(c+(e-(d^r)))");
}` -- Posting code verbatim as if we're the SPOJ site should not be done.  The code duplicates the error, doesn't require us to type in the input every single time we run the program, and makes it easier (once you get a compiler) for you to debug the issue.

Comment: Thank you all for your invaluable feedback. As suggested by @MFnx and others I did debugged my program and have corrected the error. Sry for the trouble.